# How to adjust this evaluate function by multiple percentages

Tags: c#, .net

I'm just learning c# and not too knowledgeable yet. I'd appreciate any help anyone could offer. I'm attempting to alter the base code of a popular video game for use in a mod. The full .dll I'm attempting to alter is one that determines the value of an individual human entity in the game. The specific section I'm interested in is this:

```
if (pawn.skills != null)
{
    num *= AverageSkillCurve.Evaluate(pawn.skills.skills.Average((SkillRecord sk) => sk.Level));
}
```

My question is this: Can I treat the above evaluation as an equation in any way? Can I add a variable percentage multiplier to this section? If so, how? I should specify that the terms like AverageSkillCurve refer to .dll's that cannot be edited or altered.

Comment: It's unclear what you having trouble with and what you trying to achieve. Maybe reading MSDN documentation and samples on `Enumerable.Average` is what you need?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I do know I could look for an average but there are no actual number values to average here. I want to take the value that the above function finds and multiply that by a percentage but I don't know if it's possible or how to do that.

Comment: Depending on how far you've gotten in your math education, you should know that a "percentage" is really just a fraction of 100. And of course you can multiple fractions (or their decimal representations) with other numbers. So clearly, yes "it's possible". But what are _you_ asking here? Are you having trouble understanding how to multiple a pair of numbers in C#? Are you having trouble figuring out how to select the percentage number, which to use in the multiplication? Or have you not learned about percentages yet? Please fix your question so that we can tell what you actually are asking

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. My question is based on the fact that I lack familiarity with how math and c# interact.Can I treat the output, num, as a value that I can use a multiplier on? If so is it as simple as (.5)* num ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it makes sense to apply a percentage to `num`, it is

```cs
num *= percentage / 100;
```